# Can a Kubernetes autoscaler scale based on disk usage?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, scaling, horizontal-scaling

Im looking to scale my pods/nodes based on disk space. Is it possible? I see that i can scale based on cpu or memory, but how can i scale based on disk usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use a tool named **Keda**, basically, it gives you the option to scale based on anything.

[Here](https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/scalers/prometheus/) is an example of scaling based on the sum of HTTP requests to your service; Keda will take the number directly from prometheus.

So yes you can scale pods based on disk space if you know which metrics to use